# Create a Lightning web component for creating records for master detail type

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I have two custom objects Building and flat, in this building is the master of the flat object and I have to Create an LWC component for creating new flats. in flats object since building is the master object I need to select the building in the picklist and then create the flat.
HTML.file

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Add Flats" icon-name="standard:record">
       <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        
            <lightning-combobox
                    name="Building Name"
                    label="Building Name"
                    value={value}
                    placeholder="Select Building Name"
                    options={pickListvalues}
                    onchange={handleChange} >
                </lightning-combobox>
           <lightning-input label="Name" onchange={handleNameChange} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input>
           <lightning-button label="Add Flat" variant="brand" onclick={createFlat}></lightning-button>
       </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS.file

```
import { LightningElement , wire, track  } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import  Building__c from '@salesforce/schema/Building__c';
 

export default class PicklistDemo extends LightningElement {
    @track PicklistValues;
    @track error;
    @track values;

    @wire(getPicklistValues,{
        recordtypeId : '012000000000000AAA' ,
        fieldApiName :  Building__c
    })

    wiredPickListValue({data, error}){
        if(data) {
            console.log ('picklist values are ',data.values);
            this.picklistvalues= data.values;
            this.error = undefined ;
        }
        if (error){
            console.log('error while fetching picklist values ${error}');
            this.error = error;
            this.picklistvalues = undefined;
        }
    }
    
    handlechange(){

    }

}
```

[image]

I need this kind of selection in the LWC.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying lightning input field for lightning record edit form

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Flat__c" record-id={recordId}>
<lightning-input-field field-name="BuildingId" data-id="inputBuilding">
</lightning-input-field>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lightning-record-form` to display the Full or Compact Layout,
If you want to customize more then you Can go via `lightning-record-edit-form`

Html

```
<lightning-record-form
    object-api-name={objectApiName}
    record-id={recordId}
    layout-type="Full"
>
</lightning-record-form>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement , wire, track  } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import  Building__FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Building__c';

export default class PicklistDemo extends LightningElement {
 // Expose a field to make it available in the template
    fields = [Building__FIELD];

    // Flexipage provides recordId and objectApiName
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
}
```

Attaching the Link for your reference

1. [Lightning Record Form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form)
2. [Lightning Record Edit Form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation)